# Windows 8 ListView won't render at 100% height

Tags: listview, windows-8, winjs

So, I'm making a visual page that requires a grouped ListView that grows and shrinks variably, groups can get added or removed. [Here's](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11830885/windows8tracksscreenshot1.PNG) what I want it to look like (for reference)

The various listview items (mixes) are grouped nicely, and some run off the page. This is a pretty common design pattern in Windows Store apps.

Now, here's my problem: I can only get my ListView to display properly if the `height` and `width` properties are set to a definitive number of pixels, e.g.:

```
#myListView {
height: 700px;
width: 2000px; }
```

Setting `height` and `width` to anything like 100% or a value from `calc()` inevitably causes the ListView to **not populate and not render**. According to the [Quickstart: Adding a ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465496.aspx#styling_the_listview) page on MSDN:

> For a ListView to render, you must specify an absolute value for its height.

Which is all fine and good, except this app will be on various screens and will need to be a variable height. This is especially relevant since the ListView will scroll horizontally. I want the scroll bar to appear at the very bottom of the page, the way it is in the Store app.

I've tried resetting the `height` programmatically, but that didn't work. **So, how can I get this ListView to render correctly on a variety of screens?** Below is my HTML code for reference.

```
<div id="allMixesListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
data-win-options="
 {
  itemTemplate: select('#myTemplate'),
  groupHeaderTemplate: select('#myHeaderTemplate'), 
  layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout}, 
  selectionmode: 'none', 
  itemDataSource: dummyData.placeholderData.dataSource
 }" 
class="myListView"> 
</div>
```

Comment: I have a list view with its height set to 100% that is working just fine. Could you perhaps post more of your HTML/CSS surrounding the listview div? It might have something to do with the listview's container.

Comment: Hey Paul, I figured out my problem: Even though my ListView was at 100%, its parent elements weren't, as Dominic hinted at. I changed the contenthost div that holds the page to fill the grid I defined in default.css, and set all the parent elements of the ListView to 100% height & width. Seems like your hunch was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to set the `WinJS.UI.ListView` to have `height: 100%`. However the layout that it is participating in, must also have some "defined" height. It doesn't need to be explicit (e.g. not `700px`), but it *does* need to result in some definitive space.

Example; given this HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" style="height: 100%"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The height of the DIV that the listview is on is *not* 100% of the page. It's 100% of the *parent*. Which has no height. So it sets itself as small as it needs to be. Ooops.

If you change the height from 100% to `height: 100vh`, then this layout will work because the height of the listview has been calculate to the point that the parent div takes up the space, and the ListView has some space to layout.

Note that the answer isn't strictly 'set it to 100vh'. It's "make sure that the layout has enough space to layout yours items". If you'd used a -ms-grid on the parent element, you'd have been set too (assuming rows, columns on that were set correctly)

Comment: Awesome! I set all of the parent elements height and width to 100%, up to the element where I define my -ms-grid. Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: A msdn example of an app layout implemented with vw/vh
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150600.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Your windows 8 app shouldn't ever change in height. Microsoft designed it such that the users scroll horizontally, not vertically. As such, it requires LiveView to have a definitive height. I don't believe it requires a definitive width though..

Comment: His problem is supporting the myriad of desktop heights, not it changing at runtime.

Comment: This is not true, in "snapped" mode(for example) applications could scroll vertical if the content doesn't fit into one page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx